# Running a C++ cgi program on apache?

Tags: c++, apache, cgi

I'm experimenting with compiled cgi's on a test server, but I can't seem to get them to run.

I added this to apache;

```
            <Directory /var/www/app>
            AllowOverride All 
            Options +ExecCGI 
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
            </Directory>
```

Even tried this:

```
            <Files "/var/www/app/monkey.cgi">
            Options +ExecCGI 
            </Files>
```

But every time it runs, apache tells me

```
            Fri Aug 17 01:55:07 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.66] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /var/www/app/monkey.cgi
```

I've done this before, and it's worked, but it's been awhile. Off the top of your head, can you tell me if I'm making any glaring mistakes?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any .htaccess file in your directory? And check the whole conf to see if you're not messing it up somewhere

Comment: Yep. I see it. Looks like this build of apache came with a <directory> config before where I defined it. Now I'm getting "malformed header from script. Bad header=I like monkeys you insensitive clod: monkey.cgi, referer: http://192.168.1.74/app/" which is AWESOME! I can totally fix that one. Thanks Geoffroy.

Comment: I add my comment as answer then, if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any .htaccess file in your directory? And check the whole conf to see if you're not messing it up somewhere.

Additional info: Apache does add some defaults concerning CGI scripts on some version or distributors add those defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reloading your Apache configuration? The below command line works in general:

```
sudo service apache2 force-reload
```

Otherwise might have to refer to other command line commands as based on your Linux distro as seen in link below which covers it more specifically:
http://www.microhowto.info/howto/cause_a_system_service_to_reload_its_configuration.html